# FAQ-divs show/hide example

Tags: jquery

I use following jquery code to open up (answer) div upon clicking onto (question) div in a really simple FAQ list created out of divs.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.faqlink').click(function(){
        $('.content').fadeOut(400);
        $(this).next('.content').fadeIn(400);

    });
});
```

This faq list is supported by a simple CSS..

```
 .content {  display:none; }
```

Works nice. What I'm missing here is a solution to hide "content" div upon clicking onto same "faqlink" div - again - the one which opened that question.

Is it possible using this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fadetoggle()

```
$('.content').fadeToggle();
```

fadeToggle() combines both fadeIn() and fadeOut(). If it is faded out, then it fades in, and vice versa.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanx :D Please be patient for a minute or so to accept answer ;)